# REST API design suggestion

Tags: api, rest

I am designing an API and I need input on the design.

Consider this use case where we have Schools & Students:

We want to create reports based on the performance of students in previous exams.

Now I can choose to generate a report based on the following parameters:

1. School Name (All students in the specified school)
2. ZIP code (All students in the specified ZIP code)
3. Student ID (Single student specified by ID)
4. Student standard (Student studying only in the specified standard)

Should I have 4 separate POST endpoints for this purpose or one common endpoint which chooses which flow to use after validating the payload?

Comment: Does it matter? Can you figure out the pros and cons yourself for each? I don't see a big problem with either approach.

Comment: Why do you need to design an API when in REST you should use a media-type that supports a server in explaining what a client can do next, i.e. through forms or link-relation names URIs are returned for? Just [read up](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) on what Fielding said on this matter. The spelling of URIs in REST architectures is (and should be) irrelevant to clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I have 4 separate POST endpoints for this purpose or one common endpoint which chooses which flow to use after validating the payload?

If you are doing something like returning a report produced using parameters specified in the request *body*, then it really doesn't matter whether you use one URI, four URI, or many URI.  Choose whatever option makes life easier for the people you care about (programmers trying to integrate with your API, or technical writers trying to describe it, or operators trying to monitor traffic and trouble shoot, or customers looking at their browser history) -- pick someone and figure out what works best for them.

---

If you are using POST requests to *modify* reports on your servers, the ideal case is to use the *same* URI that is used to GET a copy of the report.  The idea here is to leverage the [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons) policy that is built into the HTTP standard.

If your POST request modifies *more than one* of the resources on your server... well, we don't have a standardized general purpose mechanism for describing all of the cached responses that we want to invalidate - so you pick the most important one, and use that.

Answer (score 3):

I would choose 4 different endpoints. I find it simpler to document the API and to write a client for multiple different endpoints because all of them will have only a single acceptable message body format.

Answer (score 1):

I agree a lot with @inf3rno's answer but I would add a counter point in favor of a single endpoint in that, if the functionality is very similar, it might be worth just having a single endpoint and adding a query parameter to specify the type of report e.g. `/report?type=zip`.

You could then document it almost as well as four separate endpoints without having to actually make four endpoints.

Comment: I think the question is opinion based. Though I never understood why it is not allowed here to write a dozen different opinions so the questioner can choose between them...

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a matter of preference. I would say that if the question is asking for opinions e.g. "what's the best programming language?", that should be removed but if the OP is genuinely asking for best practice, but unaware that it's entirely subjective, I would be inclined to agree with you that it should be allowed so they can learn from the answers they get.